# Why is the Hazard function not a pdf?

Tags: survival, density-function, hazard

I am trying to understand why the hazard function is not a PDF. For a random variable T, people often define the PDF of this random variable as:

$$f(t)=\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{P(t\leqslant T <t+\delta)}{\delta}$$

By this definition, the hazard should also be a conditional PDF.

$$\lambda(t)=\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{P(t\leqslant T < t+\delta \mid T\geqslant t)}{\delta}$$

Seems like the two functions share the same type of definition! They are the limit of a probability. So why is one a PDF and the other not?

I guess is the reason this is not a PDF because the conditioning is not on a single event $T=t$ but rather on $T\geqslant$? If it were on a single event $T=t$, would this be a PDF?

Comment: It can be a constant value for all positive numbers (e.g. for an exponential distribution) and thus, for a start does not necessarily integrate to 1.

Comment: yes that's what led me to realize it is not a pdf. But I am trying to understand whyyy it is not a pdf if the definition looks like its a pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *argument* of a conditional pdf cannot depend on the *conditioning event* in any way, shape or form.  In 
$$f_{T\mid A}(t\mid A) = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{P\{t < T \leq t+\delta\mid A\}}{\delta},$$ $A$ can be a *fixed* event such as $\{T>5\}$ but not something that depends on $t$ such as $\{T > t\}$.

Another important reason why a hazard function $h(t)$ (or any scalar submultiple thereof) cannot possibly be a pdf is that
$$\int_0^\infty h(t)\, \mathrm dt =  \infty$$ whereas pdfs of lifetimes have more mundane values for their integrals: 
$$\int_0^\infty f_T(t)\, \mathrm dt =  1.$$

Comment: It is not always the case that the hazard rate has infinite integral.  If the integral is finite this just means there is some non-zero probability of infinite survival.  In many applications it is assumed that this is impossible, but some applications allow it.

Comment: @Ben Unless otherwise stated most vehemently, most readers would assume that a random variable is a mapping from $Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ (and not to $\mathbb R^+$) and so $\infty$ is not a "value" that a random variable can take on with positive probability.  Note that your random variable violates the _set-continuity_ property (equivalent to the Third Axiom) of probability measures.

Comment: @Ben And the readers who do use the extended reals will evaluate the integral of the hazard rate as infinite regardless, because a positive probability of an infinite value gives an infinite expectation. (In other applications where $-\infty$ also has nonzero probability, the integral would be undefined.)

Comment: @Dilip: I think it is preferable to encourage readers not to make that assumption.  It is a strange assumption to make.  After all, when we deal with essentially the same process with something like a Poisson process, we allow for a Poisson count of zero, which is equivalent to the event never occurring.  Another problem is that some readers will encounter a hazard integral that is infinite, and find your assertion that this is impossible confusing.  Perhaps you could just stipulate the assumption (or the contrary case) in the answer.

Comment: @Dilip: Also, it is perfectly okay to specify a random variable on $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$; it is just one extra element.  It just has some different properties than a real random variable, but so what?  Deciding to restrict the range of the random variable *prior to consideration of the problem* is surely more problematic than just letting the random variable be what it will be.

Comment: @whuber: Since it is difficult to debate this issue in a comment thread, I have created a new question to resolve the matter: [Must the hazard function integrate to infinity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432548/)

Answer (score 2):

I think the counterexample Björn suggested is a enough to answer the question. Let me write it out in more detail:

#### Björn's Counterexample

Let $T\stackrel{d}{=}\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ for any $\lambda > 0$ then $f_T(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ which implies $S(t) = \mathcal{P}(T>t) = 1-(1-e^{-\lambda t}) = e^{-\lambda t}$.

The hazard function can be calculated as $\lambda(t) = \dfrac{f_T(t)}{S(t)} = \dfrac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{e^{-\lambda t}} = \lambda$. (hence the notation $\lambda(t)$ for a hazard function).

Clearly this implies that $\lambda(t)$ is not a probability density function, since $\int_0^{+\infty} \lambda(u) \mathrm{d}u \not = 1$.

#### Back to your question(s)

The first part of your question was:

> `Why is one a pdf and the other not'

As far as I remember, $f_T(t)$ is defined as a pdf if *certain conditions hold*. One of these conditions is $\int_\Omega f_T(t) \mathrm{d} t =1$. (Which can clearly be violated in the case of $\lambda(t)$).

The density function $f_T(t)$ can be *viewed* as the limit of a cumulative distribution function in a *narrow timeslot*, which is what the notation $f_T(t) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{\mathcal{P}(t\leqslant T<t+\delta)}{\delta}$ suggests. I would not call this the definition since it lacks the conditions.

> I guess is the reason this is not a pdf because the conditioning is not on a single event $T=t$ but rather on $T\geqslant t$? If it were on a single event $T=t$, would this be a pdf?

Notice how:

$$
 \mathcal{P}(t\leqslant T<t+\delta \mid T = t) = 1
$$
which implies that conditioning on $T=t$ isn't that usefull.

A conditional probability function $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=x)$ for continious r.v. is defined as
$$
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=x) = \dfrac{f_{Y,X}(Y=y,X=x)}{f_X(x)}
$$
and the hazard function does not fit here. You need (at least) two different random variables. You could look at something like this:

$$
f_{T \mid Z}(t\mid Z = 1)
$$
for a certain $Z$ as an indicator of treatment or control. Then cleary this is a probability function.

Answer (score 1):

The Hazard function can be equivalently seen as the ratio of the pdf $f(t)$ to the survival function $S(t)$:

$$\lambda(t)=\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{P(t\leqslant T < t+\delta \mid T\geqslant t)}{\delta}$$
by definition of conditional probability:
$$=\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{P(t\leqslant T < t+\delta \cap T\geqslant t) / P(T \ge t)}{\delta}$$
$$=\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{P(t\leqslant T < t+\delta) / P(T \ge t)}{\delta}$$
by definition of $f(t):$
$$= \frac{f(t)}{P(T \ge t)}$$
by definition of survival function:
$$ =\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$$

Thus since the hazard function is the pdf scaled by the survival function, it will not generally integrate to $1$, and hence is not a pdf.